# Accessing postgresql in review stage of Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-ci

How do I import data to the postgresql server during the Review stage (for a review app) during the Gitlab CI/CD process?

I am currently using Gitlab CI/CD to deploy to AWS. Postgresql is used throughout the build stages.

During the build stages, information is successfully imported to postgresql from another application. The data is then dumped as a SQL file to an artifact (in two locations).

```
artifacts:
    paths:
      - postgres_backup.sql
      - scripts/postgres/postgres_backup.sql
    expire_in: 1 day
```

The build artifacts are created. However, they are not available in the review - autodeploy - stage.
The review stage is basically:

```
review:
  extends: .auto-deploy
  stage: review
  before_script:
    - echo "Supposedly, this helps to carry over artifacts."
```

The artifacts are not there. Ideally, I would want to push the SQL backup to the database but 1) the artifact is not available and 2) the `psql` command is not available (nor apt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `.auto-deploy` job (it might be coming from an [included job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) [this too](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#use-extends-and-include-together)). If the `.auto-deploy` job has a `dependencies` keyword, it's affecting your artifacts.

By default, when one job uploads artifacts, jobs in all following stages will automatically download the artifact. This can be controlled using the `dependencies` keyword on individual jobs.

For example, using `dependencies: []` means this job has no dependencies, so no artifacts are downloaded. `dependencies: ["npm install job"]` means that the artifacts from a job called "npm install job" are the only artifacts downloaded, even if artifacts from other jobs are uploaded.

So if you see the `dependencies` keyword in the `.auto-deploy` job, you'll have to include it in your `review` job. If `.auto-deploy` has `dependencies: []`, you'll have to have `dependencies: ["your-job-name"]` where the job name is the job that uploads the files.

If `.auto-deploy` has a `dependencies` keyword that has at least one job name, you'll have to copy the jobs, and include them in your `review` job:

```yaml
// .auto-deploy job:
.auto-deploy
  stage: deploy
  dependencies: ["job1", "job2"]
  script:
   - ...
```

```yaml
// review job
review:
  stage: review
  dependencies: ["job1", "job2", "your-postgres-job"]
  script:
    - ...
```